# using Velocity to create SOAP message

Tags: java, velocity

I need to create a SOAP message using Velocity. I am just wondering how would I be able to get a SOAP message object from the Velocity Template? as far as I know that Velocity Template is evaluated into String.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Velocity just outputs a `String`, so you have one option: re-parse the XML into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is still relevant, you can generate your SOAP XML message using velocity (as a String) and then do a POST using a plain HTTP client. Are you using some kind of framework which makes it necessary to have the velocity output to be deserialized into SOAP message object?